# ifelse() not working correctly using mutate: R

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I have a small doubt in ifelse confition. I've read numerous articles and tried different solutions but I'm not able to solve it. Please help me with it.

I have a column of numbers ranging from 0:59 and it recurs like this for 500 rows.
I am trying to create another column which divides 0:29 as 0 and 30:59 as 30.

Data:

```
> data$Minute
   [1]  0  0  0  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  3  3  4  4  4  5  5  5  5  5  6  6  6  7  7  7  7  7  8  8  8  8  8  8  9
  [38] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 12 12 12 12 13 13 13 13 13 14 14 14 14 14 14 15 15 15
  [75] 15 15 15 15 15 15 16 16 16 16 16 17 17 18 18 18 18 18 19 19 19 19 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 21 21 21 21 21 21 21
 [112] 22 22 22 22 22 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 25
 [149] 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 26 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 28 29
 [186] 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31
 [223] 31 32 32 32 32 32 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 34 35 35 35 35 35 35 35
 [260] 35 35 35 36 36 36 36 36 36 36 36 37 37 37 37 37 37 37 37 37 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 39 39 39 39 39 39 39
 [297] 39 39 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 42 42 42 42 42 42 42
 [334] 42 42 42 42 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 44 44 44 44 44 44 44 44 44 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45
 [371] 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 47 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48 48
 [408] 48 48 48 49 49 49 49 49 49 49 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 52 52 52
 [445] 52 52 52 52 52 52 52 52 52 53 53 53 53 53 53 53 53 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 54 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55
 [482] 55 56 56 56 56 56 56 56 56 56 56 56 56 56 57 57 57 57 57 57 57 57 58 58 58 58 58 58 58 58 58 59 59 59 59 59 59
 [519] 59 59 59 59 59 59 59  0  0  0  0
```

Code:

```
data<- data %>%  mutate(Period = ifelse(((Minute >=0) && (Minute <= 30)),0, 30) )
```

While running this code, I am only getting Period value as 0 for all the data points. Can you please help me with this small issue?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Please read this post on [How to ask Good Questions and compose Minimal Working Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: What other information would you need?

Comment: Please check now.

Comment: `&&` is for single conditions, you need `&`, the vectorized version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```r
data %>%  mutate(Period = ifelse(minute <= 30, 0, 30))
```

Comment: Wow! That worked, thank you so much! But, I am still not sure why the error was coming before.

Comment: As written in a comment under your question, you should have used the single `&`. 

However, in this particular case it was not necessary because the range of minutes is from 0 to 59, so a minute <= 30 is necessarily > 0